# Are results of "quantum eraser experiment" same both for particles moving at the speed of light and slower ones?

Tags: relativity, fermions, measurement-problem, bosons, quantum-measurements

Recently I've encountered a video about the [quantum eraser experiment](https://youtu.be/0ui9ovrQuKE). I was curious, if results of this experiment are the same for entangled particles moving with the speed of light and slower ones?

Comment: Not all bosons move at the speed of light. Pions and carbon-12 nuclei are just two examples of massive bosons (and nothing massive can travel at the speed of light).

Comment: You're right. I edited the question so that it's more precise.

Comment: @probably_someone is every elementary boson maseless?

Comment: @lineage No. The W and Z bosons, as well as the Higgs boson, are massive.

Comment: @brzepkowski in theory they should be as the expt. only requires 1. entaglement 2. wave -particle duality and entangled systems can be massive.

Comment: I'm asking, because I've read in the comments under the video, that photons do not experience time. So, for entangled photons it would "take 0 time" for the first one to arrive at the first detector and also "0 time" for the second photon to arrive at detector 2, 3 or 4. And I was interested, if the same results apply to particles, that "experience time" in a way similar to ours.

Comment: People performed double-slit experiments using electrons and Helium atoms (http://doi.org/10.1038/386150a0). I believe nobody has performed a delayed-choice quantum eraser experiment using these "particles", yet. However, if somebody does, I know on which outcome I would bet. As Michio Kaku once said: "The only thing that quantum theory has going for it is that it is unquestionably correct".

Comment: @brzepkowski The idea that "the quantum eraser experiment works because photons don't experience time" is very very common -- the _majority_ of people exposed to a standard (bad) explanation of the quantum eraser come up with just that idea. You might have posted the hundredth question we have along these lines.

Comment: But unfortunately, it doesn't really make any sense, since the experiment does not depend at all on its constituents moving at the speed of light. Hell, the constituents could even be stationary and it would still work. If you know how to write the Schrodinger equation, you can see that for yourself.

Comment: The real answer to the question is that, well, the confusion is all manufactured. The problem is that every "explanation" of the quantum eraser coming out of the quantum optics community is incredibly bad and intentionally confusing, with the perverse goal of making it sound a lot more mindblowing than it actually is. Unfortunately, "deterministic, local evolution under the Schrodinger equation continues to work" doesn't get as much attention.

Comment: Could you provide some more details on the solution based on the Schrodinger equation (as an answer, or maybe a link to some materials)?